# MySQL: copy values from table to another by condition

Tags: mysql

I need to copy values from "points" table (where user.id = points.user_id and points.type = 'all')

for all users

tables structures:

user:

```
id      name      points
1      John          0
2      larry         0
3      sara          0
4      sand          0
5      Mary          0
```

points:

```
id     user_id     type     value
1          1       all       34
2          1       cat        5
3          2       all        2
4          3       day        1
5          4       all        55
```

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UPDATE user u JOIN points p ON p.user_id=u.id
    SET u.points=p.value
        WHERE p.type='all';`